# McAfee Update download script

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, mcafee

I'm setting PC with McAfee install on them and be told that I need to stop the program going on line to download update (DAT). I need to create a script to download dat file from McAfee web site and put this file on server where McAfee can access and install this.

Has anyone done this in past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have done this. I haven't tested this script in a year or two but here is what I was using. This isn't written in Powershell but if you change the directories I think this can run on Windows.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ftplib
import tarfile
import shutil
import os
import re
import time

scannerDir = "/usr/local/uvscan/"
tmp = "/tmp/avscanner/"

def downloadDat():
    datfile = ""
    r = re.compile("^avvdat")
    ftp = ftplib.FTP("ftp.nai.com", "anonymous", "email@yourdomain.com")
    ftp.cwd("/pub/datfiles/english")
    list = ftp.nlst()
    for x in list:
        if r.search(x):
            datFile = x
    f = open(tmp + "datfile", 'wb')
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + datFile, f.write)
    f.close()
    ftp.quit()

def unpackDat():
    tFile = tarfile.open(tmp + "datfile", 'r')
    for f in tFile.getnames():
        tFile.extract(f, tmp)

def createDirs():
    if os.path.isdir(tmp) == False:
        os.mkdir(tmp, 0700)
    os.chown(tmp, 0, 95)
    os.chmod(tmp, 0755)

def doCleanup():
    shutil.rmtree(tmp)

def installFiles():
    shutil.copyfile(tmp + "/avvclean.dat", scannerDir + "/avvclean.dat")
    shutil.copyfile(tmp + "/avvnames.dat", scannerDir + "/avvnames.dat")
    shutil.copyfile(tmp + "/avvscan.dat", scannerDir + "/avvscan.dat")          

def isOld():
    if os.path.isfile(scannerDir + "/avvclean.dat"):
        if time.time() - os.path.getctime(scannerDir + "/avvclean.dat") < 80000:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return True

def main():
    if isOld():
        createDirs()
        downloadDat()
        unpackDat()
        installFiles()  
        doCleanup()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I keep getting these erros. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Script\mcAfee Script2.py", line 64, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Script\mcAfee Script2.py", line 57, in main
    createDirs()
  File "D:\Script\mcAfee Script2.py", line 35, in createDirs
    os.chown(tmp, 0, 95)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'chown'

Comment: This script used to run on Linux. Probably just need to remove the chown lines or find a Windows equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for the script. I have test this on my PC by installing python. but I can't install python on server I have to look for powershell or vb script.

Comment: @Lalajee It is Python.